# "Watch" directory using GStreamer and decode new media files on the fly

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing, decoding, amazon-kinesis

Suppose I have a directory, `/tmp/media`, into which some video-producing device continually writes timestamped (in the filename) 60s MP4s, keeping an hour's worth of history, e.g.

```
(written at 13:42, deleted at 14:42) /tmp/media/video-2019-05-18T13:41:00.mp4
(13:43) /tmp/media/video-2019-05-18T13:42:00.mp4
(13:44) /tmp/media/video-2019-05-18T13:43:00.mp4
```

In other words, it's a continuous video stream from a camera broken up into 60s chunks.

Is there a way to "watch" this directory using gstreamer, decoding new files as they arrive?

My goal is to publish them to a Kinesis Video Stream using their GST plugin per the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/gs-send-data.html). For single files I believe I can use `filesrc`, but I was wondering if there's a non-clunky way to keep pushing new files as they come into the directory to the stream.

Comment: You don't need exactly watch that directory. You can use a cronjob to every minute check that /tmp/media and convert/publish videos.

Comment: I’m trying to maintain a constant stream without interruptions, though.